# PHP Session State Not Saved

Tags: php, session

I am working on a Web chat application. I recently ran into a problem where a particular session variable is not being saved. I have no clue why this is happening as everything else appears to work fine. Code:

This is the class that invokes the function the command is associated with. It is called like this: Command::process("whois", "username_goes_here");

What could be the possible problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Quick note, possibly because the data you are setting cannot be or is not serialized. We found this to be a problem when we were setting objects, we had to serialize them before we stored them in session.

Comment: I am dealing with a String data type. It doesn't have to be serialized. In MinteCommand_elevate(), $_SESSION['minte']['admin'] is equal to the admin hash, but in Command::process(), it is a blank string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need to save Objects in a session, please note, that the object's class needs to be loaded before the saved Objects get back to life from the session.

In this case, load the object's class definition first, then read the object from a session.

**PS:** Hopefully, the value of `$command` doesn't get passed directly from the HTTP request into the function...